# variable to switch the pre-requisites for a target in a Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I wish to use 'MY_TYPE' to switch the prerequisites for the target 'top'.

based on MY_TYPE Can I select the pre-requisites required

For example, for

MY_TYPE=FOO , I wish to have  $(BUILD) $(TARGETS) $(X_LOCALS) as pre-requisites for top

MY_TYPE=BAR , I wish to have  $(BUILD) $(TARGETS) $(Y_LOCALS) as pre-requisites for top

How can I achieve it?

Below is a simple code snippet.

```
BUILD = build
TARGETS = targets
XLOCALS = xlocals
YLOCALS = ylocals

# can be FOO or BAR
MY_TYPE ?= FOO

$(BUILD):
    printf "\t Doing Build\n"

$(TARGETS): 
    printf "\t Doing target\n"

$(XLOCALS):
    printf "\t my local build for X \n"

$(YLOCALS):
    printf "\t my local build for Y \n"


# based on MY_TYPE Can I select the pre-requisites required
# For example, for 
# MY_TYPE=FOO , I wish to have  $(BUILD) $(TARGETS) $(X_LOCALS) as pre-requisites for 'top' target
# MY_TYPE=BAR , I wish to have  $(BUILD) $(TARGETS) $(Y_LOCALS) as pre-requisites for 'top' target
# How can I achieve it .

top: $(BUILD) $(TARGETS) $(XLOCALS)
    printf "\t doing top\n"
```

Happy to take your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing easier, just use [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax):

```
ifeq ($(MY_TYPE),FOO)
top: $(X_LOCALS)
endif

ifeq ($(MY_TYPE),BAR)
top: $(Y_LOCALS)
endif

top: $(BUILD) $(TARGETS)
        @echo prereqs are $^
```

Comment: Hi Beta, I tired your suggestion on the code snippet. I am still unable to get the XLOCAL or YLOCAL called by the target top.

Comment: @user2532296: I am unable to reproduce your error. When I put my conditionals in your makefile (and correct `X_LOCALS`=>`XLOCALS`) and `make top`, it works perfectly. I'll post a complete example you can try...

Comment: Sure, I can try the example once you post it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, had an issue with tab spacing.